# What's wrong with my usage of glBindTexture?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am rendering a chess board, using 2 different textures. One for the black squares and one for the white squares. However instead of each different square having their own texture, they all take on the last texture that I bound calling `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);`.

This is my approach:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // square 0, 0 ( front left )
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBlackSquare->texID);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-8.0, 0.5,  8.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-6.0, 0.5,  8.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-6.0, 0.5,  6.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-8.0, 0.5,  6.0);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // square 1, 0        
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureWhiteSquare->texID);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-6.0, 0.5,  8.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-4.0, 0.5,  8.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-4.0, 0.5,  6.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-6.0, 0.5,  6.0);
glEnd();
```

When I run this code, both quads have the white texture bound. How do I get each quad to have its own texture?

Comment: Please elaborate in your question title. No-one else will recognise your question from it at present, and this is a _community_ not a support site for one-offs.

Comment: Again I apologize, I was not sure what to put for my title, and I was hoping my issue was a simple fix that could be explained in a sentence or two. It is hard to predict the scope of a problem, when you are not sure what the problem is in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot call `glBindTexture` in the middle of `glBegin/End`. You can only call vertex functions within begin/end.

Also, why don't you just make a single texture as an 8x8 checkerboard, and then just render a single quad to draw the whole checkerboard?

Comment: I wanted to bind the textures to each square separately because my program is actually interactive and the textures need to be updating dynamically for each square.

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glBindTexture.html):

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if `glBindTexture` is executed between
>   the execution of `glBegin` and the corresponding execution of `glEnd`.

You forgot to check for errors, and thus missed that your program is invalid.

Comment: **Note:** It took me 1 minute and 14 seconds to look up that manual page via Googling "glBindTexture", and to find something to explain why your code wasn't working, and then to write it up here.

Comment: My mistake, I was not even aware of a GL_INVALID_OPERATION so I did not know to check for it. The program executes fine, and binds textures, just not in the order I expected. This made me think it was something trivial that I did not understand about textures.

Comment: @pixelpusher: ... which is always the best time to look it up in the documentation!

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a texture within a glBegin-glEnd block. Also you should avoid switching textures where possible, since switching the texture is among the most expensive things you can ask the GPU to do (a texture switch invalidates all texel fetch caches).

Instead you sort your scene objects by the texture they use and group them by this. So you first render all checkerboard quads using the first texture (say white), and after that all the quads using the second texture (black then).